# I'm using an if statement, which is supposed to break the loop. Can Someone help me? (Swift Playgrounds)

Tags: loops, if-statement, nested-for-loop

//the loop didn't break. Which is weird. I tried to fix it, but it didn't work. I tried the same code in python. Same thing happened.

```
let code = "QQQQQQQQ"
let characters = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!@#$%^&*()-=+_"
var cracker = ""

for letter in characters {
    for letter2 in characters{
        for letter3 in characters {
            for letter4 in characters {
                for letter5 in characters {
                    for letter6 in characters {
                        for letter7 in characters {
                            for letter8 in characters {
                                cracker = "\(letter)\(letter2)\(letter3)\(letter4)\(letter5)\(letter6)\(letter7)\(letter8)"
                                print(cracker)
                                if cracker == code {
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single break will only get you out of one loop, not all of them. Instead of doing it this way, what you should do is make another function for the whole loop. In python->

```
def check(characters):
    for letter in characters :
        for letter2 in characters:
            for letter3 in characters :
                for letter4 in characters :
                    for letter5 in characters :
                        for letter6 in characters :
                            for letter7 in characters :
                                for letter8 in characters :
                                    cracker = "\(letter)\(letter2)\(letter3)\(letter4)\(letter5)\(letter6)\(letter7)\(letter8)"
                                    print(cracker)
                                    if cracker == code:
                                        print("Found")
                                        return;
    print("Not Found!")
    return
```

So, when you find an answer, print something like "FOUND" and return so you know you found the answer and if you didn't find the answer, at the end of all loops print something like "Not found" and return.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Just wondering. If I put 8 break statements. Would that also work

Comment: Yeah of course it will work BUT you need to add another statement in all of your loops to keep a check on the outer levels. Like when you break out of the innermost loop(because of a condition satisfied) make a var=1 and just after each loop, check if var is 1 and if it is then break out of the loop and do the same in the next outer loop and so on. It can be done but I believe its unnecessary :)